# How do I keep words inside a div?

Tags: html, css

I have this code but when I run it the word is half way out of the div at the bottom

```
<a href="index.html"><div id="homebuttonlink">
  <b><p style="font-size: 30px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">Home</p></b>
</div></a>
```

Comment: I don't see the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/2MLSW/ Please share a bit more details.

Comment: Your markup is out of whack. An `a` tag should not be holding a `div` or a `p` tag within it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `white-space:nowrap;`

**For Instance,**

```
<p style="font-size: 30px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; white-space:nowrap;">Home</p>
```

Hope this helps.